# How to set function properties/attributes from within the function definition?

Tags: python, function, functools

How to set function properties/attributes from within the function definition?

For example is there a way to achieve this from within the function definition:

```
def test():
    pass

test.order = 1
```

So something along the lines of:

```
def test():
    self.order = 1
    pass

print(test.order)
```

Comment: Why do you need this?  You want to read the function's local variable?

Comment: @scriptboy I want to use a function as input for another function, yet have some logic which is dependent on the input function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, function is also an object, so of course you can set attributes of a function.

But the function's attributes are not related to function's logic, so you may want to define them outside the function. `decorator` might be a good choice.

```
def function_mark(**kwargs):
    def decoractor(func):
        func._my_info = kwargs
        return func
    return decoractor

@function_mark(order=1)
def test():
    pass

print(test._my_info)
```